# Correct duplicate records in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table that contains many records, in which there is a `nic` column  which should have unique value. But it contains some dirt, means there are some duplicate values there.

Like user with

```
id = 567 has nic = '786-786'
```

and also

```
id = 897 has nic = '786-786'.
```

I want to write a stored procedure what should remove those duplicate and append 1 at the end like

```
id = 567 , nic= '786-786'
id = 788 , nic = '786-786-1'
id = 2344, nic = '786-786-2'
```

Is it possible?

Comment: tag mysql... for what db engine you need query, ms sql or mysql?

Comment: it's `MSSQL engine`.

Answer (score 0):

use a window function / analytic function such as

`Row_number() over (partition by Nic, order by ID)`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d00b0/1)
Something like...

```
UPDATE B
SET B.Nic = C.NewNic
FROM Foo B
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, NIC + '-'  + cast(Row_number() 
over (partition by NIC order by ID ) as varchar(20)) as newNic
FROM FOo) C
 on C.ID = B.ID
```

This will give you

```
id = 567 , nic= '786-786-1'
id = 788 , nic = '786-786-2'
id = 2344, nic = '786-786-3'
```

You could always do a case statement and when row is 1 then not display and subtract 1 if you have to leave the first one without a -1

[SQL Fiddle getting rid of the -1 for first record...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a242a/1/0)

```
UPDATE B
SET B.Nic = Case WHEN C.RN = 1 then B.Nic Else B.Nic+ '-'+cast((RN-1) as varchar(20)) end
FROM Foo B
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, NIC, cast(Row_number() 
over (partition by NIC order by ID ) as varchar(20)) as RN
FROM FOo) C
 on C.ID = B.ID
```

Resulting in:

```
ID  NIC
567 786-786
897 786-786-1
```

and a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/860ea/2/0) showing multiple nic's

```
ID  NIC
567 786-786
600 786-786-1
897 786-786-2
10  786-787
12  786-787-1
900 786-787-2
```

Comment: not working, giving syntax error at `Inner join` 2nd line and on 3rd line 'as`.

Answer (score 0):

for tsql

you can do this by simple update, try this query:

```
select id, nic, rank() over (partition by nic order by id)
from your_table as t1
where exists(select 1 from your_table where nic = t1.nic and id <> t1.id)
```

You can build update query, or return update string as field of this select. Read about [rank()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms176102%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)